# Confused about command from the command pattern and command in CQRS

Tags: design-patterns, cqrs

Am I correct in thinking that the `command` in [CQRS](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html) is very different from the command from the [command pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern)?

From what I've read, the command in CQRS is a data transfer object (DTO) with no behaviour. But the command in  the command pattern essentially *only* has behaviour?

Would it be sensible to call the *command pattern* commands "handlers". Which would implement a `Handler` interface with `execute()` and `undo()` methods (so it is fairly obvious that I am implementing some form of the command pattern). And reserve `Command` for CQRS commands?

Answer (score 3):

The *C* in CQRS has the meaning of *Change Model* , it's unrelated to the Command Pattern, although many times a CQRS app is using the said pattern as well. CQRS refers to the models only: have one suitable for changes (domain,Business) and a simpler one for querying.

There is no 'reserved' keyword, when you're saying CQRS everyone who knows the meaning will know it's about the different models. The changes can be triggered by commands which get handled, but usually ppl are using *Command* for all messages that will change the model (and Events for all messages depicting changes that happened).

Answer (score 1):

MikeSW is right. The 'C' in CQRS is not the same thing as the command in the command pattern. Command handlers are also different from commands with 'Execute' methods. Essentially a handler is a domain service, responsible for pulling together all thats needed in order to issue the command to the domain.

Another point to note is that typically a command is not a DTO in the sense it is a property bucket with getters and setters. They are often implemented as immutable classes. This makes for a more reliable and predictable system that is easier to test and multi thread if necessary.

For more on this and an over view of the various parts of a typical CQRS system check out [CQRS - A Step-By-Step Guide to the Flow of a Typical Application](http://danielwhittaker.me/2014/10/02/cqrs-step-step-guide-flow-typical-application/)

Hope you find that useful.

Comment: "Essentially a handler is a domain service" Not always. Very often is an application service. But as a general 'rule' command handlers can be considered services. And I'm considering any message (command and events) a DTO without any encapsulation.